# VS Build tools 2022 not showing up on capabilities of Azure agent pool

Tags: azure-devops, build-tools, visual-studio-2022

Recently I updated our build server's VS2019 buildtools to VS2022 BuildTools. But i do not see the latest VS2022 buildtools in the System capabilities of the Azure devops Agents. I tried updating the agents, restarting the services, re-configuring the agents nothing seems to work. I even restarted the onprem build servers, still same.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: You can try to add manually

Answer (score 0):

While the update for Azure DevOps Server were not announced, you should update your on-premise environment manually, please refer to the official GitHub:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/3641#issuecomment-984680900